# type script: how to specify type of array.splice

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an enum

```
export enum LanguageType {
  EN = "en",
  ML = "ml",
  TH = "th"
}
```

and a function like

```
export const getLanguage = (path: string): Maybe<LanguageType> => {
  const components = path.split("/").filter(v => v !== "");
  return components!.length >= 2 ? components[1] : null;
};
```

I want to specify the function `getLanguage` should return value from `LanguageType`

Comment: If `components[1]` exists, are you sure it will be one of those `en`, etc?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a type assertion to indicate that the `components[1]` is a `LanguageType`:

```
export const getLanguage = (path: string) => {
    const components = path.split('/').filter(v => v !== '');
    return components.length >= 2 ? components[1] as LanguageType : null;
};
```

Note that TS can infer the shape of the function just fine - there's no need to specify the return type in the function definition.

You can also filter by Boolean instead of checking against the empty string if you want to make the code a bit shorter, thanks @Kousha:

```
export const getLanguage = (path: string) => {
    const components = path.split('/').filter(Boolean);
    return components.length >= 2 ? components[1] as LanguageType : null;
};
```

Comment: A little shortcut, you can do `path.split('/').filter(Boolean)` as well